# Is a Windows 10 recovery drive transferable between machines?

Tags: windows-10

I have two Acer laptops both using Windows 10.  The laptops are not identical and the installations of Windows 10 are clearly not identical.  For one thing, the older and smaller machine does not find any "create recovery drive" command the way the newer bigger one does.

I have created a recovery drive on the newer machine.  Would I be able to use that on the older machine if the need arose?  I suppose in a disaster i could try it and see.  But I wonder if anyone here can tell me.

Would it create an authentication problem?

This is different from the question [Reinstall Windows 10 from recovery drive (USB) onto empty hard drive fails (with vague error message)](https://superuser.com/questions/1071924/reinstall-windows-10-from-recovery-drive-usb-onto-empty-hard-drive-fails-with?rq=1) because I am not talking about wiping my hard drive.  I am just talking about the kind of system malfunction that would normally be solved by a recovery drive.

Comment: The WinRE partition is not connected to the system in any way.  It also does nothing that an ordinary Windows 10 installation media disk does

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, according to the website https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-windows-10-recovery-drive/

with one significant condition:

> You can also use a different computer running Windows 10 to create a
>   recovery drive, then use it on your own to repair it. Just make sure
>   the computer you use to create the drive shares the same system type
>   (32- or 64-bit) as your own.